# MySQL retrieving rows beween two dates from a DATETIME field

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

I am a newbie to Zend Framework 2 and now I'm facing an issue with MySQL’s `DATE()`. I am unable to retrieve records between two dates in Zend Framework.

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `assignee` = 1 AND date(`start_date`) BETWEEN "2017-03-01" AND "2017-05-25"
```

What I’ve tried in ZF2:

```php
public function getTaskCheck() {
  $sqlstatement = $this->taskTable->getSql()->select();
  $sqlstatement->columns(['*']);
  $sqlstatement->where('tasks.assignee=1');
  $sqlstatement->where->between('DATE(start_date)', '2017-03-01', '2017-05-25');

  return $this->taskTable->selectWith($sqlstatement)->toArray();
}
```

But this is showing error as unknown field `DATE(start_date)`. In the database `start_date` field is stored as `DATETIME`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try to replace where between line to: $sqlstatement->where->between('start_date', '2017-03-01', '2017-05-25'); I think, there is no reason to cast that value to date.

Comment: start_date field is stored as DATETIME

Comment: That's no matter... If you execute that query SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `assignee` = 1 AND start_date BETWEEN "2017-03-01" AND "2017-05-25", it will be work anyway.

Comment: you can use \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression